# Html 5 Local Storage not persistent in firefox

Tags: html, storage, local

I made a simple function

```
localStorage.setItem('foo', 'bar')  
alert(localStorage.getItem('foo'));
```

If I run it like this it works.
If I remove the first line after I run it once and I let only this

```
alert(localStorage.getItem('foo'));
```

I get a null value in Firefox 3.6.12
In chrome it works.

Any ideas ?

Comment: How did you open the file with the above code? Trough a web server, or from the file system directly?

Comment: It works on a web server. How come ?

Comment: It's a security feature, file:/// URLs are restricted in what they can do in Firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug [ https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=507361 ]